# Proving an inequality result regarding positive numbers $a,b$ with $0<a<b$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $a,b$ be positive numbers such that $a<b$ and let $x \in (0,
>  \frac{a+b}{2} ) $.
>
> a) Prove that $\dfrac{1}{x+a} - \dfrac{2}{a+b} > \dfrac{2}{a+b} -
>  \dfrac{1}{b-x} $
>
> b) Use a) to prove that $\displaystyle\int_a^b \dfrac{ dx}{x} >
>  \displaystyle\int_a^b \dfrac{2dx}{a+b} $

### Attempt:

For a), we can write $\dfrac{a+b}{(x+a)(b-x)} > \dfrac{4}{a+b} $ . and thus

$$ \dfrac{ (a+b)^2 }{2^2 } > (x+a)(b-x)$$

I get stuck here. Am I on the right track? Part b) is more manageable:

$$\dfrac{1}{x} > \dfrac{1}{x+a} >  \dfrac{1}{x+a} - \dfrac{2}{a+b} > \dfrac{2}{a+b} -
 \dfrac{1}{b-x} > \dfrac{2}{a+b} $$

and so by transitivity

$$ \dfrac{1}{x} > \dfrac{2}{a+b} $$

and thus integrating we obtain

$$ \int_a^b \dfrac{dx}{x} > \int_a^b \dfrac{2dx}{a+b} $$

as desired. Is this a correct proof?

Comment: a) is on the right track. Hint: Consider using the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: AM-GM inequality with $A = x+a $ and $ B = b-x$ ? But, we may not have $b-x > 0$

Comment: Yep. We do certainly have that; look at how x is defined.